# Combine to JSON HTTP POST requests?

Tags: java, android, json, servlets, google-cloud-messaging

I am a starting programmer, and for school I have to make a servlet, and an Android app.

A server sends a request to my servlet with JSON like this:

```
{
"function":"authenticate",
"requestId":"[random]",
"deviceId":"[android deviceid]",
"serviceType":"GCM"
}
```

The servlet reads the JSON and uses authenticateRequest() to send the notification:

```
    else if(function.equals("authenticate"))
    {
        // Get the deviceId
        String deviceId = jsonRequest.getDeviceId();

        // Get the serviceType
        String serviceType = jsonRequest.getServiceType();

        GCM gcmClass = new GCM();

        // Send authentication request to the user
        int authenticationResult = 0;
        if(serviceType.equals("GCM"))
        {
            authenticationResult = gcmClass.authenticateRequest(deviceId, requestId);
        }
        if(serviceType.equals("APNS"))
            authenticationResult = 70000;

        // Set the result field
        jsonResponse.setResult(authenticationResult);

        // Set the result text
        if(authenticationResult == 0)
        {
            jsonResponse.setResultText("OK");
        }
        else if(serviceType.equals(10000))
        {
            jsonResponse.setResultText("DENY");
        }
        else if(serviceType.equals(70000))
        {
            jsonResponse.setResultText("Unsupported");
        }
        else
        {
            jsonResponse.setResult(50000);
        }
        // Set the requestId field
        jsonResponse.setRequestId(requestId);

        // Send the JSON response
        response.getOutputStream().print(gson.toJson(jsonResponse));
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
    }
```

authenticateRequest (at this point it always says status 0 (which means always ALLOW):

```
public int authenticateRequest(String regId, String requestId)
{
    try
    {
        String messageText = "New authentication request received!";
        Sender sender = new Sender(Config.GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY);
        Message message = new Message.Builder().timeToLive(30).delayWhileIdle(true).addData(Config.MESSAGE_KEY, messageText).addData("requestid", requestId).build();
        result = sender.send(message, regId, 1);
        return 0;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 60000;
    }
}
```

Now the Android app receives the requestId and I am able to use that to send another JSON HTTP POST request to the servlet.
The android app needs to send an ALLOW of DENY to the servlet and the servlet should return that in the same session as the first request was received.

But I can't seem to figure out how to do this, been stuck at this point a couple of days now.

I would be very grateful is someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself! :D

This is what I was looking for:

```
class Authenticate {
    boolean flag = true;
    String finalUserInput = null;

    public synchronized String sendAuthentication(String deviceId, String requestId)
    {
        // Send notification
        GCM gcmClass = new GCM();
        gcmClass.authenticateRequest(deviceId, requestId);

        while(flag)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        flag = true;
        notify();
        return finalUserInput;
    }

    public synchronized void receiveAuthentication(String userInput, String requestId) {
        finalUserInput = userInput;
        flag = false;
        notify();
    }
}

class T1 implements Runnable {
    Authenticate m;
    private final String deviceId;
    private final String requestId;
    String result;
    public T1(Authenticate m1, String deviceId, String requestId)
    {
        this.m = m1;
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.requestId = requestId;
        Thread t1 = new Thread(this, "sendAuthentication");
        t1.start();

        // Wait for thread to finish before sending response
        try
        {
            t1.join();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
       result = m.sendAuthentication(deviceId, requestId);
    }
    public String getResult(){
        return result;
    }
}

class T2 implements Runnable {
    Authenticate m;
    private final String requestId;
    private final String userInput;
    public T2(Authenticate m2, String requestId, String userInput) {
        this.m = m2;
        this.requestId = requestId;
        this.userInput = userInput;
        Thread t2 = new Thread(this, "receiveAuthentication");
        t2.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        m.receiveAuthentication(userInput, requestId);
    }
}
public class AuthenticationHandler {
    final static Authenticate m = new Authenticate();

    public static String sendRequest(String deviceId, String requestId)
    {
        T1 runnable = new T1(m, deviceId, requestId);
        String result = runnable.getResult();
        return result;
    }
    public static void receiveResponse(String requestId, String userInput)
    {
        new T2(m, requestId, userInput);
    }
}
```